# Set default focus for ActionBarSherlock Tab

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I implemented ActionBarSherlock to display TAB in fragment activity, but wan to set defult focus to some other tab rather set it always to first one.

any one have idea how can set default focus in case of TAB here?